# Consider $A=^*B$ if and only if $A\triangle B$ is finite, What type of relation is $=^*$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

Consider $A=^*B\iff A\triangle B$ is finite ($\triangle$ is the symmetric difference)  what type of relation is $=^*$

First i start by checking if it is reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive.

so for reflexive i have put let A be a set then $A=^*A \iff A\triangle A$ is finite so $A\triangle A=(A\setminus A)\cup (A\setminus A)=\emptyset$ which is finite (since $(A\setminus A)=\emptyset$) thus $A=^*A$ so the reflexive property holds?

Now for anti-symmetric:  if $A=^*B$ and $B=^*A$ then $A=B\iff A\triangle B \land B\triangle A$ are finite, now i've gone on to show that $A\triangle B= B\triangle A$ but how do i show that they are finite? (or is it sufficent to show that they are equal and state that $A,B$ non-empty but if they was empty then surely they would just both be equal to $\emptyset$ .)

Now for the transitive property : If $A=^*B$ and $B=^*C$ then $A=^*C$  would i use the result that $A\triangle B$=$B\triangle A$ ? i'm not too sure what to do here.

if it was to satisfy these three properties then it would be a partial ordering and if it satisfies the Trichotomy law then it would be a total ordering.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like a badly phrased question or trick question. In case you're translating from another language, are you sure it doesn't ask what type of _relation_ $=^*$ is? In that case the answer would be that it's an equivalence relation -- but one wouldn't usually call that a "type of ordering".

Comment: You're correct, it says what kind of relation sorry, i couldn't read my supervisors hand writing, luckily since you say it is an equivalence relation then instead of trying to show anti-symmetry holds i would just show symmetry holds?

Comment: In fact you should be able to prove that it's _not_ antisymmetric fairly easily by showing a concrete counterexample.

Comment: i've only been able to show $A\triangle B$=$B\triangle A$ i cant seem to think of an example that is not finite. could you enlighten me?

Comment: A counterexample to "antisymmetric" would be sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A=^*B$ and $B=^*A$ yet $A\ne B$. Why do you think you would need to find an infinite symmetric difference for that?

Comment: It looks to me like your first goal here should be to _get an intuitive understanding of what the $=^*$ relation does_. Frankly, your attempts here look like you _don't_ have that understanding and are just trying to wing it by doing symbolic manipulations blind without caring about their _meaning_.

Comment: You're right in that, i dont know why i was trying to find and infinite symmetric difference when clearly $A\ne B$ i was overthinking it,Thank you.

Comment: Would you be able to show me a solution for the symmetric and transitive property? in this case for the symmetric property would we start with that  $A=^*B$ iff $B=^*A$  and since $A=^*B$ iff $A\triangle B$ is finite then $B=^*A$ iff $B\triangle A$ is finite however $A\triangle B = B\triangle A$ i dont know where to go from here..

Comment: I don't understand what you think is missing there.

Comment: For showing transitivity, note that $A\triangle C=(A\triangle (B\triangle B))\triangle C=(A\triangle B)\triangle (B\triangle C)$, since $\triangle$ is associative. And $X\triangle Y \subseteq X\cup Y$; in particular $X\triangle Y$ is finite if $X$ and $Y$ are.

Comment: So leaving it there would be sufficient to show that it is symmetric? Why do I not need to show that $A\triangle B$ is finite this is the main confusing point are we just to assume both sets are finite?

Comment: If you're assuming that $B\triangle A$ is finite and know that $A\triangle B=B\triangle A$, then how can you think you need to do more to show that $A\triangle B$ is finite? I'm really confused about what you think is missing here. $A\triangle B=B\triangle A$ means that $A\triangle B$ _is the same set as_ $B\triangle A$; if that set is finite when you call it $B\triangle A$, then it will be just as finite when you call it $A\triangle B$.

Comment: But surely this on the condition that A & B are finite right, I haven't wrote that down and it seems crucial ?

Comment: Where would you get an assumption that $A$ and $B$ are finite? I don't see anywhere you could get such an assumption from, but I don't see why you would need one either. (If you have proved $A\triangle B=B\triangle A$ only for finite $A$ and $B$, you need to go back and prove it for arbitrary sets first, of course).